# 1.a numbering of subfigures within a figure without a caption

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I am using the `subcaption` package and write a caption for each of my subfigures. In order to get a reference to "Fig. 1a", I also have to write a "big caption" below all subfigures. But I don't want to write this "big caption" always. Anyway, I want my figure to have the label "Fig. 1a".

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{An Elephant.}
        \label{fig:elephant}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{A Mouse.}
        \label{fig:mouse}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{"Big caption". How can I avoid this one and get the label "Fig. 1a"?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(My question is not about the format of the number (e.g. "1a" or "1.a") but about "how do I get the "1" in my "1a"-reference)

Comment: Can you please complete your code snippet to a running [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Instead of image `elephant` and `mouse` you can use package [`MWE`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) with the included example pictures.

Comment: ... or the `demo` option of the `graphics` package.

Comment: You mean that you want the caption to say `Figure 1.a` but without any real caption at all... Is that right? What if you just write `\caption{}` is this what you want?

Comment: @Thanos: Writing `\caption{}` writes an extra line with "figure 1" which uses space I don't have ;-)

Comment: @Vincent See Axel's comments on my answer below. I know you already got a satisfactory answer but, for the benefit of future visitors, could you clarify your question a bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way of producing the desired output; there may be better ways.

Wherever you want that numbering system for `subfigure`s within a `figure` that lacks a `\caption`, use, at the beginning of the `figure` environment in question, the `\nocaption` command defined in my code below.

See section 6 of the [`subcaption` manual](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) for more details.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\nocaption{%
    \renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\nocaption
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{elephant}
        \caption{An Elephant.}
        \label{fig:elephant}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{mouse}
        \caption{A Mouse.}
        \label{fig:mouse}
    \end{subfigure} 
%\caption{"Big caption". How can I avoid this one and get the label "Fig. 1a"?}
\end{figure}

Fig.~\ref{fig:elephant} shows an elephant; Fig.~\ref{fig:mouse}, a mouse.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could wrap the code into a `\nocaption` command: `\makeatletter\newcommand{\nocaption}{\renewcommand\p@subfigure{}\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure.\alph{subfigure}}}\makeatother` (add the linebreaks)

Comment: @egreg Yes, thanks. I don't know why I didn't do it that way in the first place.

Comment: Why defining `\nocaption` when the (sub)caption package offers `\phantomcaption` for this purpose? And why using either `\nocaption` or `\phantomcaption` if this isn't necessary at all? I'm confused...

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I think the OP wants the caption numbering system to be of the form 1.a. I'm not sure `\phantomcaption` is enough; don't you need to redefine `\thesubfigure` for that?

Comment: @Jubobs Maybe, but what has this to do with the main caption? Why is the questioner asking about the main caption, if his real question should be "Hey, my refs are shown as 1a, but I want 1.a, how to do it?"

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I think adding a figure caption was the OP's way of obtaining a caption numbering of the form 1a for the subfigures (i.e. `\thefigure\alph{subfigure}`). S/he was asking about how to replicate that numbering format without having any figure caption. This is turning into a thread. We should clean up all those comments when the confusion clears up.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for clearing this, I now see what you have done and why do have it done this way. I must confess that after reading the question I never would have thought in this direction. (Furthermore the `subfigure` package is claimed to be used but the example code uses the `subcaption` package.)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt No problem. I've kindly asked the OP to clarify his question.

Comment: alright, I just read it and @Jubobs, you are right. I will clarify my question.